# Source / Sink invariant under coordinate transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

In nonlinear dynamical systems theory, if an equilibrium point is classified as a sink or a source using one system of coordinates, that is, the differential equations are written using one set of variables/coordinates, do the points retain their sink/source/saddle behaviour under a transformed set of variables/coordinates?

Thanks.

Comment: Related (very): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605691/why-does-a-saddle-remain-a-saddle-when-you-change-coordinates/2605726#2605726

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a saddle remain a saddle when you change coordinates?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605691/why-does-a-saddle-remain-a-saddle-when-you-change-coordinates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming the transformation  is a $C^{k}, \quad k\geq 1$, diffeomorphism.

Suppose we have two systems $\dot{x} = f(x)$ and $\dot{y} = g(y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, related by a change of coordinates $y=h(x)$. Then, assuming $h(x)$ is a smooth diffeomorphism, we have $f(x) = (Dh(x))^{-1}g(h(x))$. Now let $x_{0}$ and $y_{0}=h(x_{0})$ be the corresponding equilibria. Then

$$Df(x_{0}) = Dh(x_{0})^{-1}Dg(y_{0})Dh(x_{0})$$

and the eigenvalues of $Df(x_{0})$ and $Dg(y_{0})$ are the same.